# vim and sed single liner: negate search, multiple search the substituted line, open file and highlight in vim editor

Tags: bash, vim, sed

Following is what I am want to do in one line:
1. Search for lines that do not match a pattern in file ak.txt, substitute each line with `\<the negate matched line\>\|`:

```
$ sed -n '/.*[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/!s:.*:\\\<&\\\>\\\|:p' ak.txt
```

Output:

```
\<ee integration_01.32.00\>\|
\<ration_01.2.000\>\|
\<gon_1.21.000\>\|
\<dkei_ting-on_1.2.00\>\|
\<see integration instructions\>\|
```

Above works, I don't want last two characters on last line though ...
2. Asking 'VIM' to multiple highlight the substituted line searches, throws error, below is command:

```
$ vim -c "/`sed -n '/.*[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/!s:.*:\\\<&\\\>\\\|:p' ak.txt`" -c 'set hls' ak.txt
```

Error:

```
bash: .: unrecognized history modifier
```

I guess we got what I am trying to get, How do we tell BASH through VIM and SED?

Comment: You have an exclamation mark in a double-quoted string, which bash hates. Replace it with `"'!'"`.

Comment: @minitech found a sed exception: `sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unknown command: `"'`

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it in one line, then:

```
sed -n '/.*[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]*$/!{ s:.*:\\\<&\\\>\\\|:; $s/\\|$//; p; }' ak.txt
```

or:

```
sed -n '/.*[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\{3\}*$/!{ s:.*:\\\<&\\\>\\\|:; $s/\\|$//; p; }' ak.txt
```

This takes your basic operation, but uses the `{` and `}` to group 3 actions.  The first is your substitution operation, unchanged (I was tempted to change the `:` into `/`, but didn't).  The second only matches the last line of the file, and removes the trailing `\|` that seems to be your primary objective.  The third operation prints the line.

This would run into problems if the last line actually matched dd.dd.ddd at the end (where d represents a digit). If that's a problem, you'll probably have to use two `sed` commands (you can write it on a single line if that's what you want, but I'd not write it on a single line):

```
sed -n '/.*[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/!s:.*:\\\<&\\\>\\\|:p' ak.txt |
sed '$s/\\|$//'
```

The first line is exactly your original command; the second simply deletes the `\|` at the end of the last line.